# MERN filters and sorting. ( React + Express)

Tags: reactjs, express, filter, mongodb-query, mern

guys. I am currently creating a full-stack real-estate app using MERN stack.  The problem is i can't program at all, but i have to finish this project in a week.  I've done almost everything by watching tutorials and googling ( I know it's really bad, but i'll never try to code again in my life. //You guys are hella smart, I don't even know how are you not giving up//). So, the last problem I have is filtering the data about apartments that I fetch from db.  I want to filter them by price, district and building type ( i have all of those feilds in my mongoose database)  but the problem is that i can't find understandable tutorial about this. Can someone explain on simple examples how requesting and filtering through URL works.

I've tried to filter everything on server side, somehow it works even from frontend, but I don't see filters as parameters in my URL, i just see '/apartments" and also when i've tried to enter my filters manually in URL like 'apartments?price=5000' i don't get anything on my frontend, but it works on backend. It's very messy and this code is literally barely alive. I'm feeling so stupid. Help

Comment: I've read a Quora answer from a guy with 35y of experience saying if he doesn't feel stupid at least 5 times by the computer every day, then he's not coding anything meaningful. On the topic - can you post a code snippet of what your question is about, most of the times trying to explain the issue helps finding the solution. I'm a bit confused since you've asked about *filtering data problem* - later you said it works on the frontend,I guess that's fixed? Are you failing to GET data at `/apartments?price=5000` after a successful query from the Database -> you don't know how to send a response?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.